# What was this hack-bot trying to achieve via directory traversal?

Tags: security, linux, http, hacking

I was walking through my server logs and the following kinda stunned me:

```
ACCESS ERROR 404 from IP 62.112.152.161:
    Path: /index.php?page=weblog&env=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00

ACCESS ERROR 404 from IP 62.112.152.161:
    Path: /download.php?dlfilename=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00

ACCESS ERROR 404 from IP 62.112.152.161:
    Path: /download.php?filename=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00

ACCESS ERROR 404 from IP 62.112.152.161:
    Path: /agb.php?lang=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00

ACCESS ERROR 404 from IP 62.112.152.161:
    Path: /angemeldet.php?lang=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00
```

There were lot's more variations, always triyng to get the same file. They wouldn't succeed even if there was some "download.php"*, but I'm curious what would it do if they did.
Also, I wonder if there's something I can do against this BOT in more global scope, to help other webmasters who might have their site vulnerable against such attack.

Unfortunatelly, HTTP headers were not registered.

*I'm running on virtual server where PHP's top dir is the website's root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ironically, this is exactly the kinds of things I study in my automated security analysis research.

The bot is trying to take advantage of a PHP application vulnerability to read your password file. With success, the hacker would attempt to log into various resources including the PHP application that hosted the vulnerability, as well as, other PHP applications and services such as FTP, SMTP, SSH, etc.

You can either block the ip address and/or domain name, use a regex in your .htaccess file, or (preferred) use mod_security to block these attempts.

Mod_Security is preferred since it covers a multitude of attacks. http://www.modsecurity.org/

This is likely a compromised system that was hacked in the same way. It is likely executing a script or executable and may hit may sites before long. I do not have and attacks from this IP address in my database so it is likely new.

IP: `62.112.152.161` / Netdiscounter GmbH autonomous system - Domain Name: 441.hosttech.eu

I have other PHP application vulnerability hack attempt entries for:

> 190.hosttech.eu [ip: 82.220.34.55, asn: AS9044, BSE Software GmbH] (Sun Aug 19 2012)
>
> sh-501.premium.hosttech.eu [ip: 176.9.138.35, asn: AS24940, Hetzner Online AG] (Thu Jun 6  2013)

Comment: I just had an attack: 

--- A user with IP address 79.182.60.204 has been locked out from the signing in or using the password recovery form for the following reason: Exceeded the maximum number of login failures which is: 20. The last username theytried to sign in with was: 'admin'
User IP: 79.182.60.204
User hostname: bzq-79-182-60-204.red.bezeqint.net
---
I contacted bezeqint.net, but the mailbox there was full. Is this IP in your database?

Comment: @Leo bzq-79-182-60-204.red.bezeqint.net is not in my database, but there are 284 just like it! This is a well known network for abuses. For what it is worth, my website has cut and paste .htaccess block code that can help. My site is being revamped and expanded rapidly, so it is not as pretty as I would like, but it is functional! In fact, I am adding at least 50k domain names and IP addresses and at least 5 more major subject areas.

Comment: I get a lot of "Restricted" when trying to view your site. I just looked for a way to contact you here, but I can't find any. Perhaps you can contact me? (I have no idea how this works here on StackExchange.)

Comment: @Leo My bad!! I am having trouble with the decay algorithm and went back to a static number for a bit while I restructure the decay method. I just set the static number too high I guess. The primary reason for this site is experimentation. I set the static number quite a bit lower. In this case, it is all about access speed. It is a matter of click speed and page request speed. There is more, but not for browsers. Sorry for the problem!

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc, now I can read your site (after deleting cookies etc).

Comment: @Leo I am too tired to make too much sense of it now... but I am looking at replacing the decay rate with a table instead of the static number- that is until I fix the algorithm.

Comment: I am just learning, @closetnoc. Putting what you said on my inner shelf of things I am aware of but do not know enough about to understand yet. ;-)

Comment: @Leo I got you! I am learning too! While I have been doing this research for almost 6 years, my research is on processes rather than my becoming an expert on attacks. Some of what my system does is determining attack profiles automatically, how the attacking machine was compromised, the original IP address of the attacker, and all sorts of crazy stuff. This site was never intended to provide info, though I am working on changing that. It was a site that studied access/attacks and allowed me to silently study behaviors. I am scrambling to make the site worth a dang to others too.